# Linux TCP send splits packet when it less than MTU

Tags: c, linux, sockets

I have device that connected directly to my PC and communicates over TCP/IP. It also acts as DHCP server.

I'm trying to send simple 1027 bytes of data but somehow linux systems (so far I tried on ubuntu 18 and centos 8) this buffer is always (!) being split by two packets 825 and 202 bytes respectively.
On windows that never happens.

My code for socket communication that I use on both platforms is very simple:

```
int os_tcp_connect(unsigned long ip, unsigned short port) {
    int ret = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
    if (ret < 0) return -1;

    struct sockaddr_in server;
    
    server.sin_addr.S_un.S_addr = ((((ip) & 0xff000000u) >> 24) | (((ip) & 0x00ff0000u) >> 8) | (((ip) & 0x0000ff00u) << 8) | (((ip) & 0x000000ffu) << 24));// inet_addr("192.168.3.2");
    server.sin_family = AF_INET;
    server.sin_port = htons(port);


    if (connect(ret, (struct sockaddr*)&server, sizeof(server)) < 0)
        {
#ifdef _DEBUG           
            printf("TCP connect: %d\n", os_get_socket_error());
#endif          
            return -2;
    }
    return ret;
}

int os_socket_send(int sock, void* buff, int len, int flags) {
    return send(sock, buff, len, flags);        
}

uint8_t buff[1027] = {0,};
int s = os_tcp_connect(0xc0a80701,5005);
os_socket_send(s, &buff[0],sizeof(buff),0);
```

I also used Wireshark to check what's going on and here is what I saw:

Windows:

```
 434109     66      49913 → 5005 [SYN] Seq=0 Win=64240 Len=0 MSS=1460 WS=256 SACK_PERM=1
 434110     62      5005 → 49913 [SYN, ACK] Seq=0 Ack=1 Win=1650 Len=0 MSS=1460
 434111     54      49913 → 5005 [ACK] Seq=1 Ack=1 Win=64240 Len=0
 434120     68      49913 → 5005 [PSH, ACK] Seq=1 Ack=1 Win=64240 Len=14
 434121     60      5005 → 49913 [PSH, ACK] Seq=1 Ack=15 Win=1650 Len=1
 434122     1081    49913 → 5005 [PSH, ACK] Seq=15 Ack=2 Win=64239 Len=1027
 434123     60      5005 → 49913 [ACK] Seq=2 Ack=1042 Win=623 Len=0
```

where length 1081 is my packet 1027 + 54 bytes overhead

Linux (e.g. centos8):

```
61      74      39110 → 5005 [SYN] Seq=0 Win=29200 Len=0 MSS=1460 SACK_PERM=1 TSval=2578328767 TSecr=0 WS=1024
62      62      5005 → 39110 [SYN, ACK] Seq=0 Ack=1 Win=1650 Len=0 MSS=1460
63      54      39110 → 5005 [ACK] Seq=1 Ack=1 Win=29200 Len=0
64      68      39110 → 5005 [PSH, ACK] Seq=1 Ack=1 Win=29200 Len=14
65      60      5005 → 39110 [PSH, ACK] Seq=1 Ack=15 Win=1650 Len=1
66      54      39110 → 5005 [ACK] Seq=15 Ack=2 Win=29200 Len=0
67      879     39110 → 5005 [ACK] Seq=15 Ack=2 Win=29200 Len=825
68      256     39110 → 5005 [PSH, ACK] Seq=840 Ack=2 Win=29200 Len=202
69      60      5005 → 39110 [ACK] Seq=2 Ack=840 Win=825 Len=0
```

where length 879 is first part (825 bytes) + 54 bytes overhead and 256 is second part (202 byte) + 54 bytes overhead
Strange thing that it's always 825 + 202 split.

How can I make linux to send this packet as whole and not to split?

Comment: I'm unable to reproduce this on Ubuntu 20.04.1 with Linux 5.4.0-58-generic. I see a single `Flags [P.], seq 1:1028, ack 1, win 502, options [nop,nop,TS val 690779323 ecr 300960522], length 1027: HTTP`. `ip addr` shows my mtu as 1500.

Comment: The question I have is, are these machines/OS's communicating over the same network segments and routers/switches?

Comment: TCP is allowed to split up the data any way that it wants. TCP is a stream protocol, there are no message boundaries.

Comment: Why do you care how it's splitting it? It shouldn't affect a properly written application.

Comment: @Barmar, you absolutely right. Device's receiving is not written correctly and it fails when expected packet length not met. But I wonder how I can fix it on PC side. The most strange thing here for me is why same TCP in  windows and linux works different

Comment: Also having in mind that split is always 825+202 I suggest that there is some setting in of socket or OS itself that produce such behavior.